# How to paste a table from PowerPoint into Excel and keep cells with multiple lines as a single cell?

Tags: excel, powerpoint, ms-office, export-to-excel

I want to copy a table from PowerPoint into Excel. If I do it, all cells with multiple lines in them are converted into separate cells in Excel. Is there a way to work around this issue?

PowerPoint table:

[image: PowerPoint table]

What is copied into Excel:

[image: Excel table]

What I expected to be copied into Excel:

[image]

I expect Excel to not divide `Line1` and `Line2` into separate cells. I expect Excel to have both `Line1` and `Line2` in the same cell.

Comment: Not able to replicate your problem. My table in Powerpoint has merged cells. Upon copying and pasting to Excel, the merged cells are retained. Using 365.

Comment: Please explain with data tables or screenshots.

Comment: @Isolated I added pictures of the tables to illustrate the problem. The cells in PowerPoint are not merged, they are simple cells with multiple lines. When copied into Excel the rows that contain multiple lines is split into multiple rows and the ones that were originally in the same row (like the 'Bla' cell) is copied as a merged cell in Excel, even though in PowerPoint it's a simple cell.

Comment: @P.b I added screenshots of the tables in PowerPoint then in Excel.

Comment: Seems like Excel is trying to be smart. Line1 and Line2 is seemingly separated by a Line Break in your PPT table, which excel will treat as unique rows. If you were able to remove the line break (say, with spaces), then excel will put them in the same cell.

Comment: @Isolated yeah, correct. Well, I wouldn't even call it merged. It is a SINGLE cell, it's just that Excel seems to treat new line characters as if they were indication of a new row. There is a difference between it being merged and it being a single row. If merged, then rows 2 & 3 in Excel would still exist. But what I really want is to have only row 2, and to Excel to keep the new line characters within the contents of the cells.

Comment: @Isolated Yeah, that solution of replacing the line break with spaces could work. But I'm not sure how to do that automatically in my PPT, it's annoying to go through all the tables and do it manually. I guess a VBA script can be written for this, but I'm not familiar with VBA. In the end I will process the Excel with Python, so I guess I can make the Python logic a bit more smart instead of pre-processing the data in the PPT or in Excel...

Comment: So where does your data in the power point come from?

Comment: @P.b From someone else, I don't have control over that data. I just want to parse it.